# Global Variables Between WPF Windows

Tags: c#, wpf, variables, global-variables, global

I'm developing my first WPF application and I am confused as to how to share some information between multiple WPF Windows. Whenever you say global variable, everyone seems to shreak but in WPF I'm not sure how I'd get around my problem without using them.

The application works as follows;

> Window 1 (MainWindow)
>
> This is the main user interface, it shall display a list of files and allow interactions to take place using these files.

---

> Window 2 (File Management)
>
> This window shall allow users to add new files to the application, as well as remove and rename existing files from the list.

(This is a high level overview, I've simplified what the application does just to make it easier to explain).

How would I pass that list of files between the two windows without storing it globally? My current thinking is to have a globally accessible class which defines both the file properties and also stores a list of the files. I would then be able to access it along the lines of:

```
App.Core.File.File
App.Core.File.FileList
```

Is this considered bad practice? Is there a better way to do it for this or any other data for that matter?

Thank you in advance.

(Note: Persistance is not needed at the moment, so I'm not storing the file list in an XML file or a DB of some sort)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would look into the MVVM pattern.  While there are many tools which would allow you to accomplish said task, from personal experience, I would recommend the MVVM Light framework http://www.mvvmlight.net/. Most other mature frameworks will be able to accomplish this as well or you can roll your own implementation.  MVVM Light includes an ability to send messages between view models, which would solve your issue.  I've been using it for a couple of years now and haven't had many complaints.

Here's an article from MSDN on the topic: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj694937.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I agree with [B.K.s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32518848/3950370), but I dont think this is a WPF problem. Each WPF window is described in a normal C# class and also gets instantiated like a normal C# object.

So your question should be: How to pass data between two C# objects?

And the easiest way to do so is to instatiate the one object from the other object, so you can pass data via methods and / or events.

For WPF, there are other options, improved for the presentation of data, but they are more complex. So if you are new to (C#) programming, the MVVM pattern could be really hard and you should start with the C# basics.

Comment: Thanks, however I'm not new to C# but instead just the idea of WPF, I think the fact they're "Windows" scared me a little, I never thought to think of them as normal objects.

Comment: I know what you mean, WPF is really big and powerful and its really hard to use alle features 'right'. I used WPF for 2 years just like WinForms, bevor I learned how to use the MVVM pattern.

Comment: I agree that MVVM can be daunting to newcomers.  The reason I recommended it right away is due to the fact that I started programming two and a half years ago.  When I dived into C#, I chose WPF as my UI framework and made a decision that I want to start doing things the right away from the get go -- thus I chose to dive into MVVM as a newbie.  It was a bit painful, but worked out for the best in my case.  I am now so comfortable with WPF and MVVM that I don't even think of it during my workflow... it's just a natural thing.